Is there a way to track "downloads" of Apple Wallet or Google Wallet for my app?
Does Google or Apple provide statistics on wallet usage through either of their developer portals?
I'd like to track or count the number of times the Mobile Wallet version of my app (the barcode, essentially) gets downloaded over a particular time or even at all. So when a user downloads my app, then notices there's an option to Add to Wallet etc. for Google and iOS, is there a way to track full successful "downloads" of the wallet? I don't want to rely on clicks of the download/add-to-wallet link itself, mostly because this behavior is actually triggered in an iFrame that I don't control, but I do own the app itself, so I don't want to go on the assumption that somebody clicking the link is actually resulting in them applying the card to their wallet.
Does Google or Apple provide statistics on wallet usage through either of their developer portals?
I've been researching online and can't find anything indicating how to track/find out the number of times a wallet has been 'added' to an account.
I realize this question does exist on Stackoverflow, but it is over 6 years old, so I'm hoping there has been some potential progress in this area!

It was already answered as : No this is not possible, Apple does not currently provide usage statistics of the wallet app. You would have to track scans of your QR code yourself.

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to track apple wallet pass usage of my application's wallet pass?

The last line of my question explicitly calls out that I realize the question already exists on StackOverflow - however it's 6 years old. I'd REALLY figure that 6 years later this could have possibly been an added metric or feature to track through the app dashboards.

If you're willing to roll your own metrics, then yes it's certainly possible. Apple offers a webhook anytime your pass is downloaded - if you use something like PassNinja.com or PassKit - this is likely handled for you.
Otherwise, you can do it yourself by setting a webServiceURL and an authenticationToken in the pass.json. Here is a related guide: https://www.passninja.com/tutorials/apple-platform/how-does-pass-updating-work-on-apple-wallet
